# How can i download images from Google Play developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I'm about to create a different version of my existing app. I need `hi-res` icon, featured graphic, and screenshots of previous application. How can I download them from Google Play developer console?

Answer (score 103):

You can use Google Chrome developer tools to find out the link to your apps graphic in the google play developer console.
The link to this graphic is like that: ***https://lh3.ggpht.com/tl0FC9sBdKWSI37JejuhKrMjlrZkZNbAJmDhaYvs6WahtRvNZC6XEiTIcyQiJ7a2QQ=h300-rw***

As you can see there is "h300-rw" at the end of this link. It is the dimension of your image. If you change that for example to "h1024-rw" then you'll get a hi-res image:
***https://lh3.ggpht.com/tl0FC9sBdKWSI37JejuhKrMjlrZkZNbAJmDhaYvs6WahtRvNZC6XEiTIcyQiJ7a2QQ=h1024-rw***

Comment: It's likely to be in `.webp` format. So you'll have to convert it after download.

Comment: Great answer. I don't have access to the original images because the previous developer isn't around. Anyway, I think you can download the images from the App Store. I don't know why Google wouldn't extend the same convenience to Android developers.

Comment: To get the PNG instead of a `.webp` format for the URL [above](https://lh3.ggpht.com/tl0FC9sBdKWSI37JejuhKrMjlrZkZNbAJmDhaYvs6WahtRvNZC6XEiTIcyQiJ7a2QQ=h300-rw), just remove the `=h300-rw` from the URL above and [bingo](https://lh3.ggpht.com/tl0FC9sBdKWSI37JejuhKrMjlrZkZNbAJmDhaYvs6WahtRvNZC6XEiTIcyQiJ7a2QQ=h300-rw)!

Comment: After one year, it seems still the only solution to get the images

Comment: To get the PNG image and still be able to change its dimension, you only need to remove the `-rw` part.

Comment: Can we extract features Graphics image form play store app?

Comment: You can just replace `=h150-rw` with some huge number, like `=h15000` and the largest available file will be served up.

Comment: Just to be clear, once starting the dev console, you would find this easiest under the "sources" tab, and then find something like lh3.googleusercontent.com.

Answer (score 13):

**Follow these simple steps:**

1) goto your App Page in Google Play

2) copy the **Image Address** of the image you needed `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GFLeShFxtwkDtDWMFVeieXc3nXlNwggWmh99TfwgrMANc4L3ZD2T-EEWaBbeQmjQWw=s180-rw`

3) paste it on the browser and remove `=s180-rw`

4) download thats it.

Comment: by the way, removing *-rw* is enough

Comment: hi shyam, this answer looks very similar to the approved one at a later date.

Answer (score 6):

**You can download Google Play Console images in .png by following these steps :**

- Right click on the image and click on "Open image" (on Chrome) or "Display image "(on Firefox)
- Add `=h1204` at the end of the url if you want to get the image with 1204 height (you can set any value you want)
- Add `=w1204` at the end of the url if you want to get the image with 1204 width (you can set any value you want)
- Now, you can now download the image by saving it (you will see that the format will be .PNG)

Answer (score 2):

1. Visit the app page on your computer, tap on the screenshot you wish to download.
2. `Right click` on the image and click `Open Image in new Tab`.

   [image]
3. Switch to new tab and again `right click` on the image and choose `Save Image As...`.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Jquery selector is best option to extract images from play store and app store as both stores allow web crawl.
U can find a unique class to identify image section and then crawl it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it won't show the '=s180-rw' anymore. However you can just append anything like '=s1024-rw' after the URL and it will show the 1024 image.